# How to fix "unknown url-type error" in urllib2

Tags: python, python-2.7, search-engine

I am trying to build a search engine starting with Udacity's python class.
At a point i ran my program and got this error with a whole bunch of other stuff. can somebody help me get started in making sense of all this errors.

Traceback (most recent call last):

```
  File "E:\Python codes\MySearchEngine.py", line 106, in <module>
    crawl_web(startPage)
  File "E:\Python codes\MySearchEngine.py", line 66, in crawl_web
    linksToFollow = followLinks(toCrawl)
  File "E:\Python codes\MySearchEngine.py", line 53, in followLinks
    linkPageContent = get_page(link)
  File "E:\Python codes\MySearchEngine.py", line 4, in get_page
    page = urllib2.urlopen(page).read()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\urllib2.py", line 126, in urlopen
    return _opener.open(url, data, timeout)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\urllib2.py", line 392, in open
    protocol = req.get_type()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\urllib2.py", line 254, in get_type
    raise ValueError, "unknown url type: %s" % self.__original
ValueError: unknown url type: !DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd"><html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="en-US">
```

Comment: what's the value of self.__original

Comment: i am new and don't know what self.__original means. thanks for trying to help out. am new to python

Answer (score 1):

I think I know what your problem is and that is only because I've generated a similar error myself in the past.  You need to specify a url type.  To demonstrate, look at the script below:

```
from urllib.request import urlopen as u
u('google.com')
```

When run, this little script blows up with the error: `ValueError: unknown url type: google.com`, which is your exact same problem.  However, when I change the second line to this:

```
u('http://google.com')
```

it works fine.

So, what I think you need is to add `'http://'` or whatever url type you are using to the front of `self.__original`.

Comment: yes iCodez. I changed the url format and i am actually getting to see some progress in my code. Please i'm new to python, so don't mind if my question seems dumb.

Comment: @Parousia - Of course.  We all have to start somewhere.  Just because we haven't done something yet doesn't mean we're dumb.  Anyways, if my answer solved your problem appropriately, then you should accept it (click the tick) to keep SO clean and organized.

Comment: thanks @iCodez. i think i'll keep working on the code for some time to come. for now i'm just trying to get a good handle on the python language - to reach the programmer's epiphany. but i'd appreciate if you could help me understand what "self.__original" means?

Comment: @Parousia - Well, I can't say for certain.  It is definitely an attribute of a class in the `urllib2` script.  If I had to gues, I'd say it's the URL you inputed (you know, like `'google.com'` and `'http://google.com'` for me above).